# Why is a React component not applying the style from a module less file?

Tags: reactjs, webpack, less

I used CRA to generate a new project and then added support for `less` using the less package. I have a react `Footer` component setup as follows but the class is not being applied. I use dev tools from Chrome to verify that the class `docs-footer` is not set, in fact, the footer element doesn't have any class set at all:

`Footer.module.less` file:

```
@import '~@comp/colors/dist/colors'

.docs-footer {
   padding-top: 10px;
   text-align: center;

   ... more stuff
}
```

`Footer.jsx` file:

```
import React from 'react';
import styles from './Footer.module.less'

const Footer = () => {
  return (
      <footer className={styles.docsFooter}>
      ...
      </footer>
  );
};

export default Footer;
```

webpack.config.js:

```
module.exports = {
    rules: [{
        test: /\.less$/,
        use: [{
            loader: 'style-loader',
        }, {
            loader: 'css-loader', // translates CSS into CommonJS
        }, {
            loader: 'less-loader', // compiles Less to CSS
        }],
    }],
}
```

then also using `react-script-less` on top of CRA with this part of my `package.js`:

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts-less start",
    "build": "react-scripts-less build",
    "test": "react-scripts-less test"
}
```

What can be causing this issue? Note I have also tried without having the .module convention with just `Footer.less` as file name and doesn’t work either.

Answer (score 1):

Change test RegExp `/\.less$/` to `/\.less$/i`

https://webpack.js.org/loaders/less-loader/

```
module.exports = {
    rules: [{
        test: /\.less$/i,
        use: [{
            loader: 'style-loader',
        }, {
            loader: 'css-loader', // translates CSS into CommonJS
        }, {
            loader: 'less-loader', // compiles Less to CSS
        }],
    }],
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I did that but still doesn't solve the issue. The class only shows up if I do `import './Footer.module.less' and then `<footer class="docs-footer" ...>`. There must be something else missing that it doesn't work. On the same note even if the class is added to the footer, the css settings are not applied.